# "Is there anyone on the horizon?" What does it really mean?

Tags: expressions

It happened in a conversation between 2 girls? One girl think that the other one is freaking goregous and she was like "Is there anyone on the horizon?" And the other girl was like "I don't know. I don't think I'm attractive". What does that phrase mean or I have misheard? Can anyone help me?

Comment: The origin of the expression comes from navigation. Due to earth curvation, you can't see beyond the horizon. Then, captain was asking to the watchman if there was something on the horizon (island, ship, whale, ..). In a figurative sense, "nothing in the horizon" means nothing coming soon.

Answer (score 2):

*On the horizon* is an idiom that describes a situation where something is "just imminent, or becoming apparent"

Via https://www.google.com/#q=on+the+horizon

In the context of your situation, it could mean a couple things:

1. Girl A was asking Girl B about her marital status. "Is there anyone on the horizon?" Meaning, "Are there any potential relationships in your near future?
2. Girl A was asking Girl B if anyone was around, as in, "Is there anyone on the horizon, because if so, I will have to tell you later".

Comment: Probably the first one. So wishes the girl.

Answer (score 1):

"Is there anyone on the horizon?" in this context means "Is there a romantic relationship developing with someone?" or "Is there a special someone?"

Edit: lux is correct, although given Girl B's response I think the first is more likely; she is concerned with her appearance/allure being sufficient to attract such attention (though it may be feigned, given society's obsession with appearance and self-knowledge of same).